# Replicate Color Overlay

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks, overlay

I am trying desperately hard to replicate a style that my designer applied to a stock photo for one of my websites but thus far, I have had no success.

I am trying to apply the same sort of overlay as is in the following graphic:

[image: Before and After]

I have tried the following:

- Adding a transparent rectangle on top
- Playing around with the Hue/Saturation
- Adding a rectangle layer on top and applying a 'Multiply' blend mode

So far, this is all I have been able to achieve (note the differences from the below graphic to the above graphic):

[image: What I have tried]

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve the same effect as was previously applied in either Photoshop or Fireworks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Use a Black & White adjustment layer.

2) Use a Photo Filter adjustment layer. I used a custom purple #6c118e. I made the intensity 95% and the opacity 98% (really just messing with the sliders)

3) Added a levels adjustment layer to brighten the image. I just moved the white point slider to the left, towards the middle.

4) Added overall saturation of 31+ to make the purples "pop".

Result (Mine is on the left).

[image: End Result]

Answer (score 5):

To obtain a similar result I

1. desaturated the image to **grayscale**
2. Applied the bucket paint tool in *multiply* blend mode using a purple color.

   [image]

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party as usual.

You could also simply use a gradient map adjustment layer with black and violet (as sampled from the right side of your image) for your two colors.